# Reportlab python Pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pdf, reportlab

I have this type of code which helps me to build pdf from data render from database.

But there is a problem if length of a string is too big then it overcross to other string like in billing head.

Any Solution regarding this according to my code. This Pdf built through reportlab python in django.

Image Attached.
[As you see values in Charges Description overcross the column of SAC section. I want to put half characters to next line if the length of Charges Description is too big to avoid overcross.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzfvP.jpg)

```
def sea_export_local_invoice_pdf(request, pk):
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = ' filename="local_invoice.pdf"'
c = canvas.Canvas(response)

# _______________________ get object ___________________

lir_fed = SeaExLocalInvoiceReceivable.objects.get(pk=pk)c.setFont('Helvetica-Bold', 9)
    c.drawString(85, 548, 'Charges Description')
    c.line(201, 560, 201, 300)
    c.drawString(210, 548, 'SAC')
    c.line(237, 560, 237, 300)
    c.drawString(243, 548, 'Unit')
    c.line(268, 560, 268, 300)
    c.drawString(273, 548, 'Rate')
    c.line(296, 560, 296, 280)
    c.drawString(298, 548, 'Ex.Rate')
    c.line(332, 560, 332, 280)
    c.drawString(340, 548, 'Amount')
    c.line(381, 560, 381, 300)
    c.drawString(384, 548, 'IGST')
    c.line(407, 560, 407, 300)
    c.drawString(410, 548, 'CGST')
    c.line(437, 560, 437, 300)
    c.drawString(440, 548, 'SGST')
    c.line(467, 560, 467, 165)
    c.drawString(474, 548, 'Tax Amt')
    c.line(519, 560, 519, 280)
    c.drawString(533, 548, 'Total')
    c.line(25, 540, 575, 540)

    a = '07'
    # a = ndls_gst_cd.gst_code
    b = str(sm_lir.gst_code)

    if a == b:
        gstapplied = 1
        divide_total_tax = (float(all_lir.billing_gst_amount) / 2)
        c.drawString(470, 230, str(divide_total_tax))
        c.drawString(470, 215, str(divide_total_tax))
        c.drawString(470, 200, '0.0')

    else:
        gstapplied = 2
        c.drawString(470, 230, '0.0')
        c.drawString(470, 215, '0.0')
        c.drawString(470, 200, str(all_lir.billing_gst_amount))

y = 530
i = 1
for row in lir_fed:
    c.setFont('Helvetica', 7)
    c.drawString(32, y, str(i))
    c.drawString(48, y, str(row.billing_head))
    c.setFont('Helvetica', 7)
    c.drawString(205, y, str(row.sac))
    c.drawString(240, y, str(row.qty_unit))
    c.drawString(269, y, str(row.rate))
    c.drawString(302, y, str(row.ex_rate))
    c.drawString(335, y, str(row.amount))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a different library to PDF generation, try [pdfme](https://github.com/aFelipeSP/pdfme). It wraps automatically the text inside table cells.

```py
from io import BytesIO

from django.http import HttpResponse
from pdfme import build_pdf

def sea_export_local_invoice_pdf(request, pk):
    document = {
        "sections": [
            {
                "content": [
                    {
                        "widths": [1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1.2, 1.5, 1, 1, 1, 1.5, 1.5],
                        "style": {"s": 8, "cell_margin": 2},
                        "table": [
                            [
                                {'.b': 'S.No'},
                                {'.b': 'Charges Description'},
                                {'.b': 'SAC'},
                                {'.b': 'Unit'},
                                {'.b': 'Rate'},
                                {'.b': 'Ex.Rate'},
                                {'.b': 'Amount'},
                                {'.b': 'IGST'},
                                {'.b': 'CGST'},
                                {'.b': 'SGST'},
                                {'.b': 'Tax Amt'},
                                {'.b': 'Total'}
                            ],
                            [
                                1,
                                "EMPTY EQUIP BALANCE AND HANDOVER CHARGE",
                                95.9, 2, 2, 2, '8.00', '2%', '0.0', '0.0', 0.16, 8.16
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    pdf_file = BytesIO()
    build_pdf(document, pdf_file)
    
    response = HttpResponse(pdf_file.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = ' filename="local_invoice.pdf"'
    return response
```

With this library you don't have to deal with manual creation of the table lines. You just put the content of the table in there and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You need something that can render HTML like a browser. Nothing better than Chromium. [Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) is an option you should look at. And if you do not want to bother with setting up headless Chrome, you can try out an API provided by [PDFMark.com](https://pdfmark.com)

Disclaimer: I am the developer.